# Find the distribution of the random variable given probability generating function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ be a non-negative, integer valued random variable such that $\phi_X(t)=-\log(1-qt)$. Determine $P(X=k)$ where $k=0,1,2,...$.

Now nothing is said about $q$, so maybe we can assume $q$ such that $|q|<\dfrac{1}{|t|}$. Now I proceeded as follows:

> $$\phi_X(t)=\sum_{k\geq0}t^kP(X=k)=-\log(1-qt)=\sum_{k\geq1}\dfrac{(qt)^k}{k}$$
>   By comparing the coefficients of $t$ on both sides of this power series, $$P(X=0)=0$$$$P(X=k)=\dfrac{q^k}{k}$$

Now quite surprisingly, I do not get $\sum_{k\geq0}P(X=k)=1$. To get the probability (total) $1$, I should have $\sum\dfrac{q^k}{k}=1$. But LHS is $-\log(1-q)$. Hence we need to choose $q$ such that $-\log(1-q)=1\implies q=1-e^{-1}$.

**The answer matches i.e. the answer is $P(X=k)=\dfrac{(1-e^{-1})^k}{k}$** But what kind of a question is this? Should not $q$ have been mentioned earlier? It seems that it is true for ANY $q$ which is not. Only for $q=1-e^{-1}$ is this correct.

Comment: it does make sense if they wnated to test if you understood that there must be a certain restriction on $q$ for probability to sum up to 1 (which is senssible, I guess, since most newbies miss that point and just 'assume' it does)

Comment: Tip: $\phi_X(1)=1$ is true by definition and allows you to find $q$ on a smooth way. In this context that is a good start. The question mentioned is testing a good understanding of $\phi_X(t)$. Nothing wrong with that.